# How to mount Windows drive from macOS using script

Tags: macos, mount

I am running MacBook Pro 2020 macOS 12.6.8
This is not mine but business laptop. I don't have admin privileges and I'm standard user.
I am connecting to business network using VPN (Cisco Anyconnect)
VPN lasts 24 hours ( for security reason) hence every morning I have to re-connect.
I have 5 server in the network that I have to be connected. They all are Windows.
Every morning I have to mount it again.
Initially I used Finder - Go - Connect to Server and start connections.
Now I created a file which has 5 lines like open "smb://server" and it establishes connections to all server when I execute the file.
This is much more convenient for me.
Now I have 2 questions:

1. where would you recommend me to place the file. For now I placed it on Desktop but I'd prefer if it runs every time when I start VPN or etc. i.e. not manually but automatically
2. at the end of execution I have opened Finder window. Could I put something in the file in order to close that Finder window.

Thanks in advance